# Kotlin: Use specific values as a type

Tags: kotlin

I want to model the result of two six sided dice in Kotlin.
In TypeScript you can do something like this:

```
type SixSidedDie = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6
```

I would like to do something similar in Kotlin with

```
typealias SixSidedDie =  1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6
```

Which of course doesn't work because the compiler expects a type.
Is there any way in Kotlin to use constant values as a type?

Comment: Probably an enum is the closest thing. The type system of Kotlin is not as advanced as the one in Typescript. About the last question: unfortunately not. And typealiases are not much more than a macro replacement, just mentioning this as typealiases are stronger in other languages.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way in Kotlin to use constant values as a type?

Not at the moment, and I haven't seen it discussed so far. This is because, without union types, I don't think those are really useful (you could use `object`s for that purpose).

There is an issue tracking the possible addition of denotable union types to the language: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13108/Denotable-union-and-intersection-types

Now about your precise use case, there is also nothing currently available in Kotlin to represent subsets of numbers as a type. The closest you can get, as mentioned in the comment, is an enum:

```kotlin
enum class Dice6Result {
    ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX
}
```

Or with an associated `Int` value if you need it:

```kotlin
enum class Dice6Result(val value: Int) {
    ONE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6)
}
```

Note, that union types still would not solve the `Int` subset problem unless constant values could be used as types (as you were asking for).

Another option for you could be to use a `value class` to wrap the integer value, and check in an `init` block at construction time that the value is within the bounds. However, this becomes a runtime check, which might be less interesting than an enum.